# I have a data stored in a text file I want to access that data but skipping the initial values and once the data is read then go to the next line

Tags: python

```
    with open('opcn3.txt','rt') as input_data:  
            if line.strip() == ',':          
                break                        
        count = 0
        for line in input_data:              
            count+=1
            if count == 168:
                break
            print(line)                


data_file.close()
```

DATA: I want to skip values till 40 and then start reading or printing from the first 0

27/12/2018-14:36:40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,78,12,114,1,72,97,93,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,74,100

Comment: dude, your code seems to be incorrect, where did the `line` in `if line.strip() == ',':` come from?

Comment: I want to start accessing the data after the first ',' from that line

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a solution:

```
with open('opcn3.txt', 'r') as fx:
    for line in fx:
        counter = True
        line = line.split(',')
        for thing in line:
            if counter:
                counter = False
            else:
                print(thing)
```

Comment: I have posted one more question it would be very helpful if you go through t once

Answer (score 0):

Please try my solution:

```
with open('opcn3.txt', 'rt') as input_data:
   lines = input_data.read()
   for line in lines.split(',')[1:]:
      print(line)
```

Comment: it is giving this error:                                                                                                 File "<ipython-input-58-624504cf9095>", line 2
    line = input_data.read()
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: It is still giving the initial value which I don't want